# How two change the coordinate system of dynamical system with complex eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real matrix. suppose $\lambda = \alpha + i \beta$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$ with complex eigenvector $w = u+ i v$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\bar{\lambda } = \alpha - i \beta$ and $\bar{w} = u- i v$ be the complex conjugates of $\lambda$ and $w$. Therefore,

$$
Au = \alpha u - \beta v
$$
$$
Av = \beta u + \alpha v
$$

Let $U = \text{span}\{u,v\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a two dimensional invariant subspace of $A$.
Choose coordinate system $(y_1,y_2)$ in $U$ such that every vector $x \in U$ is uniquely represented by

$$
x = y_1 u + y_2 v
$$

Suppose $x(t) \in U$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to the dynamics $\dot{x}=Ax$ and $AU \subset U$. Show that $y(t)$ satisies an ODE $\dot{y}=By$ and find $B \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinate system"? A *basis* is made up of **vectors**, then the product $y_1u+y_2v$ does not make sense.

Comment: @jobe - I agree that the description is very poorly stated in both this and other places, but it isn't that hard to figure out what Sepide is talking about. Because I don't know who is a native english speaker and who is trying to translate their terminology into a language they are not fluent in, I tend to be forgiving of these things. $(y_1, y_2) \in \Bbb R^2$, and $x = y_1u + y_2v$ is the expansion of $x$ in terms of the basis $\{u, v\}$.

Comment: @Sepide - But what I cannot excuse is that you've just stated your problem without saying anything about what you've done and where you are stuck, apparently just expecting us to do your work for you. This does not sit well with regulars of this forum. If you don't explain where you are having trouble, expect that your post will start getting close votes.